# Editing data dynamically ( grid json Ext JS 4 )

Tags: php, mysql, json, extjs, grid

I've such a simple question but can't find answer (documentation) on it. I've created Grid , where information is retrieved from **MySQL** database. Using **Ext JS 4.2** .
Let's take a look of script ...

```
Ext.define("AppStore",{
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "nickname" , type: "auto"},
        {name: "email"    , type: "auto"}
    ]
});

var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store",{
    model: "AppStore",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        api: {
            read    : "./read.php",
            update  : "./update.php"
        },
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            root: ""
        },
        writer: {
            type: "json",
            writeAllFields: true,
            encode: false,
            root: ""
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        read: function(operation, callback, scope){

        },
        update: function(operation, callback, scope){
            // Do I have to do something from here ?
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});

Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel",{
    store: store,
    selMode: "cellmodel",
    columns: [
        {
            text: "Nickname",
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: "nickname",
            editor: {
                xtype: "textfield",
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Email",
            flex: 1.5,
            dataIndex: "email",
            editor: {
                xtype: "textfield",
                allowBlank: false
            }
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        Ext.create("Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing",{
            clicksToEdit: 2
        })
    ]
});
```

Everything is working fine , just interested in how I have to send request to **MySQL** for updating data after changing it in Grid cell . Any example , documentation or the way how to accomplish this task will be appreciated , thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you'll want to call [sync()](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-sync) on your grid's store in order to persist the model changes to the server. This can be configured to occur automatically on every edit (see the [autoSync property](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-autoSync) of the store). However, I would suggest it's better to handle the sync() call based on some specific action (e.g., a "Save" button being clicked, etc.).

Comment: So with `sync()` request will be send to here `update  : "./update.php"` yes ? If yes in this case what will be passed parameters names to handle it in php side ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When you call sync() on a store, it batches together any pending create/update/delete requests that need to be made. Depending on the config of your proxy, your proxy will dynamically build the correct URL for the request. Regarding the parameters, it will send any fields in your model that are marked as persistent (default is true) and any that are changed (depending on the config of writeAllFields).